# New things and limitations in Version 12 numerical differential equation solver?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, finite-difference-method, version-12

This question is intended to be a place to summarize users' exemplary experience in solving differential equation with the `NDSolve` family in MMA’s latest version 12. 
Since there are so many differential equations and some are difficult, each time a major update may help resolve early bugs/issues and solve some new types. And certainly, many remain unable to be handled.

I personally have not yet tried much with the new solvers. Let me just list a few possible things of interest to get the ball rolling.

1. At least it is now equipped with a nonlinear FEM solver. But it certainly cannot solve all and contains bugs as well. Any info
   on that would be helpful to many of us.
2. Is it possible to control `DifferenceOrder` in `NDSolve` or `NDEigenvalue`, say, when solving an ODE?
3. What other new equations become solvable now?

---

Please feel free to edit this question.

Comment: "nonlinear PDE solver" -> "nonlinear FEM solver".

Comment: Are you asking about `DSolve` or `NDSolve` ?  If both, I think be better to ask separate question on each since these are really different functions and have different purposes. If not, then it is not clear which one are you asking about.

Comment: This question is far too vague as asked.

Comment: If subject header is changed to "...numeric differential equation solver" then it would seem to be a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: I still think the question too broad.  It could perhaps be left open as a CW question, which has been done before with posts that have a multiplicity of questions to be answered. The opening line already shows it is not a Q&A post, and the breadth of the example questions further confirm this.

Answer (score 7):

I test nonlinear FEM using solutions obtained by other methods. I developed one of these methods for the problem of the nature convection, aerodynamics, and unsteady hydrodynamics, using linear FEM - see [Solver for unsteady flow with the use of Mathematica FEM](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064) . Let me give an example. After the release of Mathematica version 12, I tested a non-linear FEM on the convection problem and compared it with my method. Surprisingly, the coincidence is one to one. The following code generates the same output as my code implementing the method of the false transient from the paper Vahl Davis, G.de (1983) : Natural convection of air in a square cavity : A bench mark numerical solution. Int. J. Numer. Methods Fluids 3, 249-264.

Code based on nonlinear FEM

```
Pr0 = .72; Ra = 10^5; R = Ra*Pr0; a = 0;
\[CapitalOmega] = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}];

{UX, VY, \[CapitalRho], TK, TX} = 
  NDSolveValue[{{Inactive[
          Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
            u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], x] + 
        u[x, y]*D[u[x, y], x] + v[x, y]*D[u[x, y], y] - 
        R*T[x, y]*Sin[a], 
       Inactive[
          Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
            v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], y] + 
        u[x, y]*D[v[x, y], x] + v[x, y]*D[v[x, y], y] - 
        R*T[x, y]*Cos[a], D[u[x, y], x] + D[v[x, y], y]} == {0, 0, 
       0} /. \[Mu] -> Pr0, {
     DirichletCondition[{p[x, y] == 0}, y == 1 && x == 1], 
     DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, 
      y == 0 || y == 1]}, {u[x, y]*D[T[x, y], x] + 
       v[x, y]*D[T[x, y], y] - (D[T[x, y], x, x] + 
         D[T[x, y], y, y]) == NeumannValue[0, y == 0 || y == 1], 
     DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0, T[x, y] == 1}, 
      x == 0], 
     DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0, T[x, y] == 0}, 
      x == 1]}}, {u, v, p, T, 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(T\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}, 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}}];
```

Compare with a bench mark numerical solution

```
MaximalBy[Table[{x, VY[x, .5]}, {x, 0, 1, .0001}], Last]

(*Out[5]= {{0.066, 68.7316}}*)

(*BenchmarkCase={x=0.066,vmax=68.59}*)

MaximalBy[Table[{y, UX[0.5, y]}, {y, 0, 1, .0001}], Last]

(*Out[8]= {{0.8543, 34.6607}}*)

(*BenchmarkCase={y=0.855,umax=34.73}*)
 MaximalBy[Table[{y, -TX[0, y]}, {y, 0, 1, 0.0001}], Last]

(*Out[12]= {{0.0747, 7.73417}}*)

(*BenchmarkCase={y=0.081,Numax=7.717}*)

 NuAv = 
 NIntegrate[UX[x, y]*TK[x, y] - TX[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 5]

(*Out[14]= 4.4880*)

(*BenchmarkCase=4.519*)


Nu0 = NIntegrate[-TX[0, y], {y, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 5]

(*Out[16]= 4.5274*)

(*BenchmarkCase=4.509*)

Nu05 = 
 NIntegrate[UX[.5, y]*TK[.5, y] - TX[0.5, y], {y, 0, 1}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 5]

(*Out[18]= 4.5252*)

(*BenchmarkCase=4.519*)

MinimalBy[Table[{y, -TX[0, y]}, {y, 0, 1, 0.0001}], Last]

(*Out[19]= {{1., 0.726786}}*)

(*BenchmarkCase={y=1,Numin=0.729}*)
```

Code based on linear FEM

```
k = 100; Pr0 = .72; Ra = 10^5; R = Ra*Pr0; t0 = 1/100; a = 0;
\[CapitalOmega] = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}];
UX[0][x_, y_] := 0;
VY[0][x_, y_] := 0;
\[CapitalRho][0][x_, y_] := 0;
TK[0][x_, y_] := 0; TX[0][x_, y_] := 0;
Do[
  {UX[i], VY[i], \[CapitalRho][i], TK[i], TX[i]} = 
   NDSolveValue[{{Inactive[
           Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
             u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], x] + 
         UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], x] + 
         VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], y] + (u[x, y] - UX[i - 1][x, y])/
          t0 - R*T[x, y]*Sin[a], 
        Inactive[
           Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
             v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], y] + 
         UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], x] + 
         VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], y] - 
         R*T[x, y]*Cos[a] + (v[x, y] - VY[i - 1][x, y])/t0, 
        D[u[x, y], x] + D[v[x, y], y]} == {0, 0, 0} /. \[Mu] -> Pr0, {
      DirichletCondition[{p[x, y] == 0}, y == 1 && x == 1], 
      DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, 
       y == 0 || y == 1]}, {UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[T[x, y], x] + 
        VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[T[x, y], y] + (T[x, y] - TK[i - 1][x, y])/
         t0 - (D[T[x, y], x, x] + D[T[x, y], y, y]) == 
       NeumannValue[0, y == 0 || y == 1], 
      DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0, T[x, y] == 1}, 
       x == 0], 
      DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0, T[x, y] == 0}, 
       x == 1]}}, {u, v, p, T, 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(T\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}, 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}}], {i, 1, k}];
```

Compare with a bench mark numerical solution

```
MaximalBy[Table[{x, VY[k][x, .5]}, {x, 0, 1, .0001}], Last]

(*Out[9]= {{0.066, 68.7316}}*)

(*BenchmarkCase={x=0.066,vmax=68.59}*)

MaximalBy[Table[{y, UX[k][0.5, y]}, {y, 0, 1, .0001}], Last]

(*Out[12]= {{0.8543, 34.6607}}*)
(*BenchmarkCase={y=0.855,umax=34.73}*)

MaximalBy[Table[{y, -TX[k][0, y]}, {y, 0, 1, 0.0001}], Last]

(*Out[16]= {{0.0747, 7.73417}}*)

(*BenchmarkCase={y=0.081,Numax=7.717}*)

 NuAv = 
 NIntegrate[
  UX[k][x, y]*TK[k][x, y] - TX[k][x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 5]

(*Out[18]= 4.4880*)
In[19]:= (*BenchmarkCase=4.519*)


 Nu0 = 
 NIntegrate[-TX[k][0, y], {y, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 5]

(*Out[20]= 4.5274*)

(*BenchmarkCase=4.509*)

 Nu05 = 
 NIntegrate[UX[k][.5, y]*TK[k][.5, y] - TX[k][0.5, y], {y, 0, 1}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 5]

(*Out[22]= 4.5252*)

(*BenchmarkCase=4.519*)

MinimalBy[Table[{y, -TX[k][0, y]}, {y, 0, 1, 0.0001}], Last]

(*Out[23]= {{1., 0.726786}}*)

(*BenchmarkCase={y=1,Numin=0.729}*)
```

Note that both methods nonlinear and linear FEM are consistent with each other and with the third method, published by Davis, G.de (1983) : Natural convection of air in a square cavity : A bench mark numerical solution. Int. J. Numer. Methods Fluids 3, 249-264.

Answer (score 4):

Re question 3:
There are [`NBodySimulation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NBodySimulation.html) and [`NBodySimulationData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NBodySimulationData.html).

Related Q&A: [(25562)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25562), [(31094)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31094), [(38478)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38478), [(63571)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63571), [(81340)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81340), [(81340)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81340), [(105342)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105342), [(121035)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121035), [(133349)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133349), [(135857)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135857), [(164196)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164196), [(181275)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/181275)

Comment: I'd be curious if someone could tell about the motivation behind these functions.  Seems like a domain-specific wrapper around `NDSolve` might be better as a package than built-in.

Comment: @ChrisK, the motivation was Stephen wanted such a function.

Comment: @user21 Would such specialized functions also follow as  `LotkaVolterraSimulation`, `MalthusGrowth`, `NSpeciesCoexistence`, `GravitationalSlingshotSimulation`, `ExponentialReplicationSimulation`,  etc.?

Comment: @IstvánZachar, I do not understand your question. Could you please try to reformulate?

Comment: @user21 I have somewhat jokingly asked whether further domain-specific wrappers for ODE solving would be implemented for other fields as well in the likes of `NBodySimulation` (ecology in this case). I know that it has been covered by a package or more recently within System under [Advanced Numerical Differential Equation Solving](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html). But the question is still valid: wouldn't domain-specific wrappers unnecessarily pollute the global namespace?

Comment: @IstvánZachar, ;-) I totally did not get that - now that I had a nap things look better....

Comment: @user21 Can't argue with that!

Comment: I think I'd prefer a more modular design that would separate the equation-setting stage (like `NBodyEquations`) from the solving stage (which could be `NDSolve`). Between this and `SystemModels` there are now three distinct clusters of functions for solving ODEs.  Ah well, I found a couple of twitch videos on the topic to watch: https://www.twitch.tv/videos/229615178 and https://www.twitch.tv/videos/329322158

Answer (score 4):

Re question 2 and `NDSolve`:

How to control `"DifferenceOrder"` at each step has been shown in [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html#51030643), which has been available for several versions.  Dynamic control of order is usually not simple, since you have to evaluate whether to change the order every step (or every $k^{\rm th}$ step).

One can control the order for certain method families, such as the Runge-Kutta ones ([explicit](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html), [implicit](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveImplicitRungeKutta.html), and [symplectic](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveSPRK.html)).
The connection between difference order and interpolation order is explored in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13836/the-only-usage-for-the-option-interpolationorder-in-ndsolve-is-to-be-set-to-all/145853#145853).